# 'Crop' a two dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im looking for a highly performant way to crop a two dimensional array. Consider this example:

I have a two dimensional array that makes up a 100x100 grid. I just want to return just a crop of it, 60x60. Here is an example of 'a' way to do it, but am looking for pointers to the most performant way of doing this.

```
// Settings
var gridWidth = 100;
var gridHeight = 100;

// Populate Grid
var grid = [];

for(var i = 0; i<gridWidth; i++){
    grid[i] = [];
    for(var j = 0; j<gridHeight; j++){
        grid[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

// Crop Grid
var rect = {x:20,y:20,w:60,h:60};

var crop = [];
for(var i = rect.x; i<rect.x+rect.w; i++){
    crop[i-rect.x] = [];
    for(var j = rect.y; j<rect.y+rect.h; j++){
        crop[i-rect.x][j-rect.y] = grid[i][j];
    }
}
```

Any thoughts greatly appreciated...

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
crop = grid.slice(rect.x, rect.x+rect.w);
for(var i = 0; i<crop.length; i++){
    crop[i] = crop[i].slice(rect.y, rect.y+rect.h);
}
```

Note that the dimensions of the array are now `rect.w` x `rect.h`, and all indices are negatively offset by `rect.x` and `rect.y` respectively.

Comment: Did you mean to write `crop[i] = crop[i].splice(rect.y,rect.y+rect.h)`? Otherwise, the indexes are just removed from the array...

Comment: @FelixKling Yup, thanks. Actually, I just realised I should have been using `slice`, not `splice`. `splice` returns removed elements.

Comment: @FelixKling No, I shouldn't have been using `splice` in the first place. I needed `slice`, it was an oversight on my part.

Comment: Wow... thanks for such a quick responses Asad and Felix! Looks like this is a really nice clean and elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
function tab(n, func) {
    for (var a = [], i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a.push(func(i));
    return a;
}

function matrix(w, h, values) {
    return tab(h, function(y) {
        return tab(w, function(x) {
            return values(x, y);
        })
    })
}

grid = matrix(7, 10, function(x, y) {
    return x + ':' + y;
})
```

this gives us:

```
0:0 1:0 2:0 3:0 4:0 5:0 6:0
0:1 1:1 2:1 3:1 4:1 5:1 6:1
0:2 1:2 2:2 3:2 4:2 5:2 6:2
0:3 1:3 2:3 3:3 4:3 5:3 6:3
0:4 1:4 2:4 3:4 4:4 5:4 6:4
0:5 1:5 2:5 3:5 4:5 5:5 6:5
0:6 1:6 2:6 3:6 4:6 5:6 6:6
0:7 1:7 2:7 3:7 4:7 5:7 6:7
0:8 1:8 2:8 3:8 4:8 5:8 6:8
0:9 1:9 2:9 3:9 4:9 5:9 6:9
```

The crop function:

```
function crop(mat, x, y, w, h) {
    return mat.slice(y, y + h).map(function(row) {
        return row.slice(x, x + w)
    })
}

cropped = crop(grid, 2, 1, 5, 6)
```

result:

```
2:1 3:1 4:1 5:1 6:1
2:2 3:2 4:2 5:2 6:2
2:3 3:3 4:3 5:3 6:3
2:4 3:4 4:4 5:4 6:4
2:5 3:5 4:5 5:5 6:5
2:6 3:6 4:6 5:6 6:6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`Array#slice` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and see whether you gain any performance improvements. Also try to avoid unnecessary computations:

```
var yend = rect.y + rect.h;
var crop = [];

for(var i = rect.x, j = 0, l = rect.x + rect.w; i < l; i++,j++){
    crop[j] = grid[i].slice(rect.y, yend);
}
```

---

You could test if it is worth to test for edge cases. For example, if `rect.x` and/or `rect.y` are `0` and you don't need the original array anymore, you can just set the `.length` of the array(s) (which modifies them):

```
var rect = {x:0,y:0,w:60,h:60};

grid.length = rect.w;

for (var i = 0; i < rect.w; i++) {
    grid[i].length = rect.h;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but that second one doesn't look like it removes the elements up to the desired y offset.

Comment: Ah darn... This would only work if `rect.y` is `0` :-/ Probably gonna delete this one then.